# IE is throwing an exception on a page with user controls and a click event, but none of the other browsers does this

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, ascx

On an external site there is a simple textbox and a button that is added using a custom control. (Just some extra event handling and custom things on a normal asp:button)
A normal email address is entered into the text box.
On IE when I press the button, before any events or post backs can even happen, it throws this error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

This only happens on IE. I'm using IE 11. We need to be compatible for all browsers.

The page in question is in a master page's content place holder.
The master page has script and such, but all the other pages that uses this page doesn't have this issue and this issue only occurs on the button click.

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: To work out why this occurs in IE only, use fiddler to capture a successful request in another browser and then do the same in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because the some character written in email could be special characters like `<`, `>`. You are getting exception because IE restricts this kind of characters to restrict hackers.

So restrict user by entering special characters using validators or javaScript and

If you still want to allow this kind of characters then write **ValidateRequest="false"** in aspx page attributre.

Comment: To note, < and > are not special characters in email addresses - see RFC2822 section 3.4.

Comment: IE restricts this kind of characters to restrict hackers. You mean ASP.net

Answer (score 0):

Add in config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Or add in page

```
<%@ Page ... ValidateRequest="false" %>
```